# Unable to remove "Run this program as an administrator" (greyed out) with Excel 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-terminal-services, uac, microsoft-excel

I have issue with one of the user in Terminal Server 2008 R2 who has **"Run this program as an administrator" checked and greyed out** with Excel 2010.

This causes UAC to popup requesting for administrator credential whenever user want to start excel.

I found in excel 2010 > properties > Compatibility tab > "Run this program as an administrator" is checked and greyed out (Unable to make any change)

This issue **only occurs in Excel 2010**, all other Office programs does not has this option checked and greyed out.

Currently **UAC is set to Default** (Second level to top)

Other users in terminal server do not have "Run this program as an administrator" checked and it is **NOT greyed out**.

The user who has issue is in the same group and has the setting as other users who doesn't has the issue in AD.

Could anyone advise me how could I remove this "Run this program as an administrator" in option in Excel 2010?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up resolved by removing User Profile for that specific user who had the issue.

Control Panel > System Properties > Advanced > User Profiles > Select User > Delete

Login with that specific user to rebuild the profile.
"Run this program as an administrator" option become unchecked after this process.

Answer (score 0):

Login with the users account and go to hkey_current_user\software\microsoft\window nt\currentversion\appcompatflags

There should be the application that has the Run as administrator option stuck, remove the entry and it should work.